# Insert a row between two known rows in Matlab

Tags: matlab, insert, interpolation

I have a set of data shown bellow:

```
                    flow Rate (L/min) 
Speed(rpm)      1      1.25      1.5     1.75    2       2.25    2.5    2.77    ...  6
                            Pressure (Pa)
2000       15251.2  15232   15200   15168   15027.2 14912   14752   0       ...  0
2050       16000    15840   15808   15744   15680   15520   15488   15232   ...  0
2100       16384    16256   16217.6 16192   16128   16064   16032   15872   ...  0
2150       17088    17024   16992   16960   16928   16832   16704   16512   ...  0
.           .            .       .       .        .       .      .       .            .
.           .            .       .       .        .       .      .       .            .
.           .            .       .       .        .       .      .       .            .
4250       61120    60800   60768   60736   60672   60736   60608   60416  ...  56960
```

At a specific speed (from 2000-4250rpm) and flow rate (from 1-6 L/min) as shown there are different pressures.

1) i want to know how can i insert a new row in between two of these speeds for example if i have a speed of 2030rpm i want to be able to find in between which two values the 2030rpm is and insert a row on matlab
demonstration hown below:

```
2000    15251.2 15232   15200   15168   15027.2 14912   14752   0   ...  0
2030    0           0     0         0     0         0      0     0
2050    16000   15840   15808   15744   15680   15520   15488   15232   ...  0
```

2) my second problem is how can i interpolate between the two values below (where the zero is and get a value.

```
15232   
  0          
16000
```

I really appreciate if any one can answer any of my questions preferably the first one so ic an actually get to the second step lol

Thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the data is stored in a matrix called `p`, for automatically positioning the new row in correct sequence:

Append the new row at the end of `p`, then:
`p = sortrows(p)`

Following up on the comments, we have:

```
newrow = [2130, zeros(1,size(test,2)-1)]
p(size(p,1)+1,:) = newrow
p = sortrows(p)
```

(if `2130` is the first value of the new row.)

Comment: Updated to indicate that `p` is the matrix that holds the data.

Comment: please bare in mind that i am not that great on matlab.how do I insert a new row at the end of p?

Comment: `p(size(p,1)+1,:) = [new row here]`

Comment: p is an 47x22 array

i put what you said and it gave me an error. then i tried 
pnew = p(size(p,1)+1,:)

and it said "attempted to access p(48,:); index out of bounds because size (p)=[47,22]

Comment: You shouldn't literally include `[new row here]`.  Instead, replace `[new row here]` with the data for your row.

Comment: my new row is not known so i have just put a row of zeros. which has inserted it at the beginning of the table.

Comment: now if i want that row in between any of the rows by knowing the first value of the first row first column what do i have to do?

Comment: Do you know the first value?  If so, create a row ahead of time: `newrow = [2130, zeros(1,size(test,2)-1)]` (if `2130` is the first value, say).  Then, append that row, as above, before calling `sortrows`.  I appended the answer to include this.

Answer (score 2):

```
newmat = zeros(size(oldmat,1)+1,size(oldmat,2))

newmat(1:x) = oldmat(1:x)
newmat(x+2:end) = oldmat(x+1:end)
```

where `oldmat`, `newmat` are the old and new versions of your matrix and `x+1` the index of the row of `0`s inserted into `newmat`.

Then, supposing that you want linear interpolation, something like:

```
newmat(x+1,:) = newmat(x,:)+0.6*(newmat(x+2,:)-newmat(x,:))
```

I expect I've made some small errors, and this is quite specific to your example, if you have trouble fixing and generalising, update your question or comment.

Comment: I have named ma set of data oldmat and i put down the formula that you gave on the first line and it gave me an array of the same size as mine but with all zero's in it.

After that what would x be? would it be the speed?

also do i have to make this as a function or just write it in the command window?

Answer (score 0):

This may help you:

```
% Matrix dimensions
nCols = 10;
nRows = 8;

% Synthetic data
matrix = [ linspace(2000,4250,nRows)' , 2000*rand(nRows,nCols-1)];
matrix([2,4],2:end) = zeros(2,nCols-1); % where some rows are zeros (2 and 4 on this example)
matrix
```

> matrix =
>
> 1.0e+03 *
>
> ```
> 2.0000    1.7810    1.3674    1.4983    0.7329    1.5439    1.5639    0.2246    0.8653    1.5379
> 2.3214         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0
> 2.6429    1.4687    1.4454    1.4801    1.3701    0.7765    0.5881    0.5831    0.2195    0.5459
> 2.9643         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0
> 3.2857    0.1458    0.2350    1.4699    1.5787    0.4579    1.0617    1.9288    0.3749    1.3466
> 3.6071    0.1771    1.2814    1.9412    0.7353    1.2839    0.1830    0.8650    0.5324    0.8591
> 3.9286    1.5967    0.6576    1.7339    0.4121    0.9690    0.8106    1.3895    1.5957    0.9035
> 4.2500    1.8860    1.3076    0.1725    0.1733    0.3037    0.2097    1.5162    0.9752    1.2197
> ```

If you just want to fill the rows whose elements from the second to the last columns are zeros with the average value of the previous and the next rows.

```
for i=2:nRows-1
  if ( sum(matrix(i,2:end))==0 )
    matrix(i,2:end) = mean( matrix([i-1,i+1],2:end) );
  end
end
matrix
```

> matrix =
>
> 1.0e+03 *
>
> ```
> 2.0000    1.7810    1.3674    1.4983    0.7329    1.5439    1.5639    0.2246    0.8653    1.5379
> 2.3214    1.6248    1.4064    1.4892    1.0515    1.1602    1.0760    0.4039    0.5424    1.0419
> 2.6429    1.4687    1.4454    1.4801    1.3701    0.7765    0.5881    0.5831    0.2195    0.5459
> 2.9643    0.8072    0.8402    1.4750    1.4744    0.6172    0.8249    1.2560    0.2972    0.9462
> 3.2857    0.1458    0.2350    1.4699    1.5787    0.4579    1.0617    1.9288    0.3749    1.3466
> 3.6071    0.1771    1.2814    1.9412    0.7353    1.2839    0.1830    0.8650    0.5324    0.8591
> 3.9286    1.5967    0.6576    1.7339    0.4121    0.9690    0.8106    1.3895    1.5957    0.9035
> 4.2500    1.8860    1.3076    0.1725    0.1733    0.3037    0.2097    1.5162    0.9752    1.2197
> ```

This code assumes that:

- You want to fill rows were only the first column element is non-zero.
- You want to replace the zeros with the average between previous and next rows values.
- You only interpolate inner rows.

I hope it helps.